# Authentication and navigation bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to set up a menu navigation on the left side of my page which is only shown up after the user logs in.

I don't know how can I achieve this with MVC4 WebSecurity class and Razor in my index.cshtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using 2 Layout:

_Layout.cshtml for non login user and

_memberLayout.cshtml for login user. 
put your member menu in _memberLayout.

/Home/Index controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Member");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

/Member/Index controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Index.cshtml in Member folder:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Member Area";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_memberLayout.cshtml";
}

<div>
         ... your member html code
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Forms authentication, take a look at User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Answer (score 0):

**Use two layout Pages**

- _Layout.cshtml
- _MemberLayout.cshtml

**Then You have two options:**

---

**First**: In _ViewStart.cshtml

Change

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

To

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MemberLayout.cshtml";
}
else
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

---

**Or:** At the beginning of every view do the following:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MemberLayout.cshtml";
    }
}
```